# Python comparing individual lists of lists elements

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare elements of lists of lists to find which values are larger/equal to each other.

```
x = [[8, 12.5], [1.5, 12.6], [35, 137], [3.8, 145], [48, 1.8], [15, 67]]
y = [[0, 14], [6.4, 224], [8.5, 123], [6.5, 26.1], [4.1, 57], [58, 61]]

if x[i,0] > y[i,0]:
   #do this
elif x[i,0] < y[i,0]:
   #do that
elif x[i,0] == y[i,0]:
   #do other
```

When I try to compare the elements, I get an error message that says:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Is there a way to compare tuple/list elements?
I see all kinds of posts that find common elements or comparing whole lists, but not comparing elements. I'm using python 2.7.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost. You get a list with the first index and then you can get an element out of that list with the second:

```
if x[i][0] > y[i][0]:
```

Comment: I do get elements, but since it is a tuple it won't accept it as a valid type to do comparisons on.

Comment: @com: You have no tuples in there. The index of `x[i, 0]` is `(i, 0)`, which is what is causing your error.

Comment: I tried changing out the brackets with parenthesis and it says:  TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @com: Use the exact code that I have in my answer. I was just pointing out the source of your error.

Comment: ah, I missed the difference when I saw it the first time.  Thank you.